# Difference between "as $key => $value" and "as $value" in PHP foreach

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I have a database call and I'm trying to figure out what the `$key => $value` does in a `foreach` loop.

The reason I ask is because both these codes output the same thing, so I'm trying to understand why it's written this way. Here's the code:

1)In foreach use `$key => $value`

```
foreach($featured as $key => $value){
  echo $value['name'];
}
```

this outputs the same as:

2)In foreach use only `$value`

```
foreach($featured as $value) {
  echo $value['name'];
}
```

*So my question is, what is the difference between `$key => $value` or just `$value` in the `foreach` loop. The array is multidimensional if that makes a difference, I just want to know why to pass `$key` to `$value` in the `foreach` loop.*

Comment: Read about [PHP arrays](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php) and [foreach](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php). In your example you don't use `$key` inside the foreach, so you might as well go for the simpler version.

Comment: Here is what the array returns:                                                              `Array ( 
[0] => Array ( [id] => 7 [name] => Shoes 2 [thumbnail] => /images/dummy-thumb.jpg ) 
[1] => Array ( [id] => 1 [name] => Game 1 [thumbnail] => /images/dummy-thumb.jpg ) 
[2] => Array ( [id] => 9 [name] => Shirt 2 [thumbnail] => /images/dummy-thumb.jpg ) 
) `   The `$key` is the `[0] [1] [2]` and `$value` are `[id] [name] [thumbnail]` correct?

Answer (score 91, accepted):

Well, the `$key => $value` in the foreach loop refers to the key-value pairs in associative arrays, where the key serves as the index to determine the value instead of a number like 0,1,2,... In PHP, associative arrays look like this:

```
$featured = array('key1' => 'value1', 'key2' => 'value2', etc.);
```

In the PHP code: `$featured` is the associative array being looped through, and `as $key => $value` means that each time the loop runs and selects a key-value pair from the array, it stores the key in the local `$key` variable to use inside the loop block and the value in the local `$value` variable. So for our example array above, the foreach loop would reach the first key-value pair, and if you specified `as $key => $value`, it would store `'key1'` in the `$key` variable and `'value1'` in the `$value` variable.

Since you don't use the `$key` variable inside your loop block, adding it or removing it doesn't change the output of the loop, but it's best to include the key-value pair to show that it's an associative array.

Also note that the `as $key => $value` designation is arbitrary. You could replace that with `as $foo => $bar` and it would work fine as long as you changed the variable references inside the loop block to the new variables, `$foo` and `$bar`. But making them `$key` and `$value` helps to keep track of what they mean.

Comment: Thank you, This is the answer i was looking for. It just confuses me when I see it used this way without using the `$key` inside the loop block. Just using it to represent that it's an associative array. I understood how the loop and array works. Just not why it was being used this way without using the `$key` variable. I have been messing around with it using the `$key` var to see what it returns. Thank you again :)

Answer (score 20):

Let's say you have an associative array like this:

```
$a = array(
    "one" => 1,
    "two" => 2,
    "three" => 3,
    "seventeen" => array('x'=>123)
);
```

In the first iteration :  `$key="one"` and `$value=1`.

Sometimes you need this key ,if you want only the value , you can avoid using it.

In the last iteration : `$key='seventeen'` and `$value = array('x'=>123)` so to get value of the first element in this `array` value, you need a `key`, x in this case: `$value['x'] =123`.

Comment: I liked this explanation, but what if instead of wanting the value i want to know the key?

Answer (score 13):

A very important place where it is ***REQUIRED*** to use the `key => value` pair in `foreach` loop is to be mentioned. Suppose you would want to add a **new/sub**-element to an existing item (*in another key*) in the `$features` array. You should do the following:

```
foreach($features as $key => $feature) {
    $features[$key]['new_key'] = 'new value';  
}
```

Instead of this:

```
foreach($features as $feature) {
    $feature['new_key'] = 'new value';  
}
```

The **big** difference here is that, in the first case you are accessing the array's sub-value via the main array itself with a ***key*** to the element which is currently being pointed to by the array pointer.

While in the second (*which doesn't work for this purpose*) you are assigning the sub-value in the array to a temporary variable `$feature` which is unset after each loop iteration.

Answer (score 8):

The difference is that on the

```
foreach($featured as $key => $value){
 echo $value['name'];
}
```

you are able to manipulate the value of each iteration's `$key` from their key-value pair. Like @djiango answered, if you are not manipulating each value's `$key`, the result of the loop will be exactly the same as

```
foreach($featured as $value) {
  echo $value['name']
}
```

**Source:**
You can read it from the [PHP Documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php):

> The first form loops over the array given by array_expression. On each iteration, the value >of the current element is assigned to $value and the internal array pointer is advanced by >one (so on the next iteration, you'll be looking at the next element).*
>
> The second form will additionally assign the current element's key to the $key variable on >each iteration.

---

If the data you are manipulating is, say, arrays with custom keys, you could print them to screen like so:

`$array = ("name" => "Paul", "age" => 23);`

```
foreach($featured as $key => $value){
 echo $key . "->" . $value;
}
```

Should print:

`name->Paul`

`age->23`

And you wouldn't be able to do that with a `foreach($featured as $value)` with the same ease. So consider the format above a convenient way to manipulate keys when needed.

Cheers

Comment: Oh boy that made a lot more sense than any of the answers, now I get the whole idea behind this :D well at least kind of :D Live long and prosper my friend

Answer (score 4):

Say you have an array like this:

```
$array = (0=>'123',1=>'abc','test'=>'hi there!')
```

In your foreach loop, each loop would be:

```
$key = 0, $value = '123'
$key = 1, $value = 'abc'
$key = 'test', $value = 'hi there!'
```

It's great for those times when you need to know the array key.

Comment: So, we set the loop this way just incase we need to know the `$key` Makes sense because this is from a function in the model in codeigniter. So may need the `$key` at a later time.

Comment: Correct. You can also use the key to change the value of that key in the array, or use it to add the data to another array using the same key.

Answer (score 4):

Sample Array: Left ones are the keys, right one are my values

```
$array = array(
        'key-1' => 'value-1', 
        'key-2' => 'value-2',
        'key-3' => 'value-3',
        );
```

**Example A: I want only the values of `$array`**

```
foreach($array as $value) {    
    echo $value; // Through $value I get first access to 'value-1' then 'value-2' and to 'value-3'     
}
```

**Example B: I want each value AND key of `$array`**

```
foreach($array as $key => $value) {                 
    echo $value; // Through $value I get first access to 'value-1' then 'value-2' and to 'value-3'  

    echo $key; // Through $key I get access to 'key-1' then 'key-2' and finally 'key-3'    

    echo $array[$key]; // Accessing the value through $key = Same output as echo $value;
    $array[$key] = $value + 1; // Exmaple usage of $key: Change the value by increasing it by 1            
}
```

Answer (score 2):

if the array looks like:

- $featured["fruit"] = "orange";
- $featured["fruit"] = "banana";
- $featured["vegetable"] = "carrot";

the $key will hold the type (fruit or vegetable) for each array value (orange, banana or carrot)

Answer (score 1):

here **$key** will contain the **$key** associated with **$value** in **$featured**. The difference is that now you have that key.

```
array("thekey"=>array("name"=>"joe"))
```

here **$value** is

```
array("name"=>"joe")
```

**$key** is "thekey"

Answer (score -1):

```
foreach($details as $key =>$values){
  if($values['created_by'] != $user->id && $values['created_by'] != ''){
    unset($details[$key]);
  }                   
}
```

Comment: Code without any explanation are rarely helpful. Stack Overflow is about learning, not providing snippets to blindly copy and paste.
 Please edit your question and explain how it answers the specific question being asked. See [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).