# Laravel - Use blade placeholder in an include

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I need to include views dynamically using the blade engine. My code looks like below:

```
@foreach($modules as $module => $value)
    @include('{{$module}}::menu')
@endforeach
```

When I go to my browser I get this error: "No hint path defined". I am new to laravel and I have no idea how to solve this. Any help would be great,

Comment: Forgot to mention it; but if I do it like this @include('module_name::menu'), it works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it should be as simple as this, assuming $modules is just an array with keys of module names:

```
@foreach($modules as $module => $value)
    @include("{$module}::menu")
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that the `$modules` variable contains any data? If not; your `foreach` will not run. Try placing this inside the `foreach`:

```
{{ var_dump($module) }}
```

Just to verify that `$module` has data.

Edit: Looks like your `foreach` loop uses the key of your array, not the value. Is that the intended behavior? See post https://stackoverflow.com/a/18492899/3903565.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried this and $module does contain data

Comment: But does it contain the value or the key of your array? Read this post about key-value pairs in associative arrays: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18492899/3903565