# What JSON-like syntax is this?

Tags: json, syntax

I'm presented with an output from a system that the documentation identifies as "JSON" but follows a different syntax. Keys with colons in them are prefixed with a colon, key/value is separated by "=>" instead of ":" and only string values are put into quotes, so it looks like:

```
{
:"key:name"=>NumericOrDateValue, 
:"key:name"=>"StringValue", 
"keyname"=>NumericOrDateValue, 
"keyname"=>"StringValue" }
```

Anyone recognize this syntax? Is there a library to convert it to normal JSON?

Comment: i found this post. It might help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18492784/difference-between-as-key-value-and-as-value-in-php-foreach

Comment: It could be Ruby:
https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Hash.html

I've found a similar question here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3183786/how-to-convert-a-ruby-hash-object-to-json

In what language do you need to consume this structure?

Comment: It is an ETL project, just trying to de-serialize the data and write it to a database; converting this to JSON would be easiest; I was hoping to identify the format to be able to search for a simple way to convert it to JSON.

Comment: It does look like Ruby except that the keys are in double quotes, not just prefixed by a colon.